# Is it possible to use functions defined in the shell from python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_test(){
    echo this is a test $1
}

my_test 1

python -c "from subprocess import check_output; print(check_output('my_test 2', shell=True))"
```

output:

```
this is a test 1
/bin/sh: my_test: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'my_test 2' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Comment: Why not saving `my_test` function in a separate shell file and run `python -c` with that shell script call from another one?

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support the `function` keyword. Use `#!/bin/bash` (or some other shell) for your shebang.

Comment: May I ask why would you want to call a function defined only in that shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to export the shell function, so it will be inherited by child shells.

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_test(){
    echo this is a test $1
}

my_test 1

export -f my_test
python -c "from subprocess import check_output; print(check_output('my_test 2', shell=True))"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I was wondering if there was a way to inherit it from python without touching the shell script. I guess that this is not possible right?

Comment: Can you put the function in another script? Then you can use `source scriptname` before trying to call the function.

Comment: Python doesn't know anything about shell scripts or functions. It just tells the shell to execute the command. If the function isn't in the shell's environment, it can't execute it. So you have to do something to get it into the environment.

Comment: Yeah, i was wondering if it is possible to get a function from the parent shell without the parent shell exporting it.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: That's the point of exporting, it's the way to allow a function to be inherited.

Comment: If you run the script with, for example, `bash -a my_script`, the shell marks all names and functions for export without having to modify the script itself.

Comment: This isn't working for me. `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` because `/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash` so I changed to `bash`. Now I get `Command 'my_test 2' returned non-zero exit status 127.` (ubuntu 18.04, bash 4.4.19, python 2.7.17)

Comment: It should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @jozxyqk I just tested it with that fix. I'm using Python 3.6.3. It didn't work with Python 2.7, I got some errors from the subprocess module, but I'm not going to worry about an obsolete Python version.

Comment: Changing to run `python3` (3.6.9) I still get the same error. On another machine where `python` defaults to 3.8.5 it does indeed work (in fact `python2` at 2.7.18 also works there). Perhaps there is some other environment setting causing problems.

Comment: What version of `bash`? I tested on a Mac running 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Exporting a function, which is not supported by all shells, places the code into the *environment block*.  This is a language-neutral block of **text**, which is copied from parent to child when a new process is created.

This was the basis of [ShellShock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)).

The trouble is that the two languages Bash and Python are totally different, so a function written in one will not be directly executable by the other without translation.  The child process could scan the environment block looking for the function, then translate and compile it into its own language.  A lot of work, and could easily be a security issue.

If you just want to go Bash->Python->Bash, then exporting the function from first Bash script should do it, because it will be copied into each environment block.  However you also state in a comment that you don't want the first script to export it.

Well you *could* read the function code using python into a text string, then put it into the environment block yourself (this is what `export` does in the shell).  Use the `os.environ` dictionary.

The actual name used is dependant on your version of Bash.  The ShellShock vulnerability resulted in a lot of changes.  Best create a test function, export it, then use `env` to find its full name.  For example on my version a simple function called `gash` appears in the environment block as `BASH_FUNC_gash%%`.

```
BASH_FUNC_gash%%=() {  echo 'Hollow world'
}
```

For example:

```
import os
import subprocess

fun_body="""() {  echo 'Hollow world'
}
"""
os.environ['BASH_FUNC_gash%%'] = fun_body

p1 = subprocess.Popen('./myscript.sh')

p1.wait()
```

The script (`myscript.sh`) contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
gash
```

Alternatively you could look at your design again.  Mixing languages is always problematic, why not write the whole lot in Python?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the os module.

```
import os
os.system("anything what you would like to do in the shell")
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps `python -c "import os; print(os.system('my_test 2'))"` still outputs `sh: my_test: command not found`

Answer (score -3):

The os module is definitely the easiest way and does not cause much trouble in a shell.